# Reading cookie expiration date

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, cookies

Is it possible to read cookie expiration date using JavaScript?

If yes, how? If not, is there a source I can look at?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It is not possible to get the expiration date of a cookie through Javascript; only key-value pairs are exposed through `document.cookie`.

Comment: Yep - after it's been set, the expiry date is opaque; it will appear in document.cookie until its expiry, at which point it will stop.

Comment: Still, it is possible to read the date if you [store it in the cookie data explicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417087/jquery-cookie-expiration-value/15221924#15221924) at creation time.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle If the cookie no longer appears in document.cookie after it expires, then this can serve as a check for expiration, no? The use case here is if you have javascript running on an interval, you can force logout after the expiration. Of course this would be coupled with a server side check as well to cover across page requests.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @Daniel, as he answered this in 2009.

But right now, I came across a similar problem and I found a better way to read the expiry date of `cookie` in Javascript.

The [CookieStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/CookieStore) type of the cookies API represents a cookie store in the browser.

**YOU CAN NOT USE THIS FOR NON HTTPS SITES**

This is compatible with all modern browsers.

All you need is to

```
// list of all the cookies
cookieStore.getAll().then(cookies=>console.log(cookies))

// returns object of the single cookie by NAME   
cookieStore.get('NAME_OF_THE_COOKIE').then(cookies=>console.log(cookies))
```

The output of CookieStore will be [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you will need to resolve it. after that result array of cookies in the following format.

```
domain: null
expires: 1615699665000 //TIMESTAMP
name: "STR"
path: "/"
sameSite: "STR"
secure: "BOOL"
value: "STR"
```

Please feel free to correct me or update my answer for the better help of others.

Comment: i use that cookiestore but received Uncaught ReferenceError: cookieStore is not defined. can you pls explain how to start using cookiestore api? i need to check if certain cookies has expires more than 10 days

Comment: @Nebula9 that happend to also me lately because this cookieStore api only supports HTTPS. but localhost should work
https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/explainer.html

Comment: https://caniuse.com/cookie-store-api poor support

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Chrome you can goto the "Application" tab (within Developer Tools) and find the item "Cookies" in the left sidebar. From there select the domain you are checking the set cookie for and it will give you a list of cookies associated with that domain, along with their expiration date.

Comment: I don't understand why this does not have more upvotes - did exactly what I needed which was to verify that my new to JS script which set a cookie was working. Thanks for this

Comment: Because it's not an answer... "Go to Chrome" is not an answer for "how to read cookie expiration date using JavaScript"

Comment: Wow, what an awesome feature. Chrome never ceases to amaze me!

Comment: it's now in a tab called "application"

Comment: @Tomino The answer doesn't exactly match the question, however, if the right answer is "it's not possible", then, would be great to read about alternative ways, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Igor Bykov - the question asked about JS because presumably they want to do something in JS according to the expiry, so looking in your browsers dev tools is no help at all. Plus everybody that does web dev already knows about dev tools - if they don't then they need to go back to school.

Answer (score 4):

There are some who will find this contentious - but one solution is to create another cookie at the same time and store the time/stamp in it parallel with whichever original cookie is created. Update them both at the same time and that way you can easily get the time from your new cookie (Alternatively append the time/stamp in your source cookie).

The reason this would be contentious is that over the years the idea of storing cookies on a users PC isn't popular because you are taking up their space. However I really doubt a small timestamp cookie would be too horrific.

Its worth remembering that if a time has passed then the browser will not report that cookie available. The browser may show the cookie present but when JS tries to access it - it won't be able too.

Additionally I found that WebDeveloper toolbar in Firefox shows cookies that have passed but under Firefox > Privacy settings they are updated correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options.

1. Save expire timestamp somewhere else - e.g. localStorage or another Cookie
2. In Chrome and Edge - use CookieStore API which i describe below

You can use CookieStore API which is "experimental" as I write, yet it's supported by Chrome. Can't test, but seems like on Edge too. Tested on Safari, it's undefined, so not supported.

Yet you can check here: https://caniuse.com/?search=CookieStore
Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/CookieStore

On Chrome sample response:

[image]

Safari 15.1 (2021-11-13):

[image]

Comment: poor support but at least it is a solution, I think this is the answer in 2022 :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the code where the cookie is set, then you can add code to store the expiration date in the browser's local storage for later retrival. For example:

```
// set cookie with key and value to expire 30 days from now
var expires = new Date(Date.now() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
document.cookie = [
    "key=value",
    "expires=" + expires.toUTCString()
].join("; ");

// store cookie expiration date for key in local storage
if (window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem("keyExpires", expires.toISOString());
}
```

Later, you can lookup when the cookie expires in local storage. For example:

```
var expires = localStorage.getItem("keyExpires");
```

Local storage currently has broad support.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to write the expiration date into the body of the cookie and then reread it from there for subsequent rewrites. I've gotten this to work with the fantastic [js-cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library.

Setting looks like this:

```
// Set cookie expiration as a number (of days)
var paywallDuration = 30;

// When you set the cookie, add the `expires` key/value pair for browsers
// Also add `expirationDate` key/value pair into JSON object
Cookies.set('article-tracker', {
  expirationDate : paywallDuration,
  totalArticlesRead: 1
}, {
  expires : paywallDuration,
  domain : 'example.com'
});
```

Reading your cookie and rewriting is straight-forward with this method. Use js-cookie's `getJSON()` method to read the expiration date you set. Then, use that date twice when you rewrite your cookie - again in the JSON object and then for the browser with `expires`:

```
var existingPaywallDuration = Cookies.getJSON('article-tracker').expirationDate;

Cookies.set('article-tracker', {
  expirationDate: existingPaywallDuration,
  totalArticlesRead: 4
}, {
  expires : existingPaywallDuration,
  domain : 'example.com'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a work-around to OP's question if you also control the setting of the cookies. I do it like this:

```js
function setCookie(name, value, expiryInDays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + expiryInDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  document.cookie = `${name}=${value}_${d.toUTCString()};expires=${d.toUTCString()}`;
}

function showCookies() {
  if (document.cookie.length !== 0) {
    const allCookies = document.cookie.split(/;\s*/);
    const wrapper = document.getElementById('allCookies');

    wrapper.innerHTML = allCookies.reduce((html, cookie, index) => {
      const cookieParts = cookie.split('=');
      const cookieValueParts = cookieParts[1].split('_');
      const cookieHtml = [
        `<b>${index + 1}</b>`,
        `Cookie name: ${cookieParts[0]}`,
        `Cookie value: ${cookieValueParts[0]}`,
        `Expires: ${cookieValueParts[1] || 'unknown'}`
      ].join('<br>');
      return html + `<p>${cookieHtml}</p>`;
    }, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showCookies()">Show me the cookies!</button>
<div id="allCookies"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if the intention of getting the `Expires/ Max Age` data is to check if the cookie has not expired, to then do some A OR B action.

You could simply check if the cookie is available as the cookies get removed after the expiration date. Info from [here](https://superuser.com/a/356266/428523)

so with tha in mind:

```
const cookie = readCookieFunction('cookieName');
if(cookie) {
  console.log(`cookie value: ${cookie}`);
  // Do A
} else {
  console.log('cookie has expired');
  // Do B
}
```