# How to get cookie expiration date / creation date from javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to retrieve the creation or expiration date of an existing cookie from javascript? If so how?

Comment: Just curious, why did you mark a wrong answer as accepted?

Comment: @nir https://stackoverflow.com/a/66621502/5657991

I guess this is the answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The information is not available through `document.cookie`, but if you're really desperate for it, you could try performing a request through the `XMLHttpRequest` object to the current page and access the cookie header using `getResponseHeader()`.

Comment: There is no such thing on the response header.
I tried: request.getAllResponseHeaders(); and it gives one thing that is close: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

but no headers related to the various cookies with their expiry time... why would it? the server has nothing to do with client side cookies...

Comment: Set-Cookie and Set-Cookie2 headers are removed from xhr response for security reasons. What you could do is set additional header with cookie expiration date on the server side and read that.

Comment: I don't think this would work

Comment: "but if you're really desperate for it"  :-(

Answer (score 45):

It's impossible. `document.cookie` contains information in string like this:

```
key1=value1;key2=value2;...
```

So there isn't any information about dates.

You can store these dates in separate cookie variable:

```
auth_user=Riateche;auth_expire=01/01/2012
```

But user can change this variable.

Comment: Good suggestion...

Comment: That may not be an issue if you need to read these on server side you can encrypt the value of say auth_expire

Comment: The biggest problem with this approach is that you're assuming clients and servers have clocks perfectly in sync–most of the time, they are not (industry standard clock skew is 5 mins). It will especially matter if your cookies are short-lived.

Answer (score 4):

you can't get the expiration date of a cookie through javascript because when you try to read the cookie from javascript the document.cookie return just the name and the value of the cookie as pairs

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible with new chrome update for version 47 for 2016 , you can see it through developer tools on Storage > Cookies under the Application tab [image], select cookies and look for your cookie expiration date under "Expires/Max-age"

Comment: In this example, can you please explain the meaning when the 'Expires' column shows 'Session' for some cookies and a date for one.

Comment: @GauravOjha if it says session then it means it expires when the server assigns you a new session and that could be done either by (A)logging out (B) Closing browser (not tab)
,,,,,but if it shows some date it means it's a manually a created cookie (some code created it and had set the date explicitly)

Comment: This works well. Btw. it's now the application tab -- not resources (mac).

Comment: The question clearly asks for it to be retrieved through Javascript.

Comment: @NeonWizard tough cookies

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @AamirAfridi it's there for reference, since this is a duplicate question, answering with only useful information usually helps people. as shown from the upvote counts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. I've separated the code in two files:

**index.php**

```
<?php

    $time = time()+(60*60*24*10);
    $timeMemo = (string)$time;
    setcookie("cookie", "" . $timeMemo . "", $time);

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Get cookie expiration date from JS
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function cookieExpirationDate(){

                var infodiv = document.getElementById("info");

                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
                }else{
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        infodiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "cookie.php", true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:cookieExpirationDate();" value="Get Cookie expire date" />
        <hr />
        <div id="info">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**cookie.php**

```
<?php

    function secToDays($sec){
        return ($sec / 60 / 60 / 24);
    }

    if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])){

        if(round(secToDays((intval($_COOKIE['cookie']) - time())),1) < 1){
            echo "Cookie will expire today";
        }else{
            echo "Cookie will expire in " . round(secToDays((intval($_COOKIE['cookie']) - time())),1) . " day(s)";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Cookie not set...";
    }

?>
```

Now, index.php must be loaded once. The button "Get Cookie expire date", thru an AJAX request, will always get you an updated "time left" for cookie expiration, in this case in days.

Comment: `intval($_COOKIE['cookie'])` Assumes you are storing the expiration in the cookie value.

Comment: @JonathanLeaders Exactly, it is being stored in the cookie value. I didn't get your point.

Comment: The OP is referring to retrieving the date from already existing cookies, not new ones we create that store the date as a separate piece of information

Comment: Oh..! Ok, that makes sense. I assumed that the OP was the one that created the cookie. My bad.

Comment: Wait ... but, isn't the cookie only accessible from the site that created it?

Comment: Probably, but there can be other applications that create cookies within the same domain that has source code that is proprietary/closed. So a site can be comprised of source you don't have access to, because the server can set cookie headers

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is to delete to cookie you are looking for the expiration date from and rewrite it. Then you'll know the expiration date.

Comment: How would this solve anything? Of course you would know if if you wrote it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Chrome you can goto the "Resources" tab and find the item "Cookies" in the left sidebar. From there select the domain you are checking the set cookie for and it will give you a list of cookies associated with that domain, along with their expiration date.

Comment: Even if this didn't address using javascript it is still useful.