# How to retrieve a cookie's expiry date with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get cookie expiration date / creation date from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274875/how-to-get-cookie-expiration-date-creation-date-from-javascript)

I haven't been able to find a solid answer to this issue. I have a cookie set to expire in 15 days after a user signs in. I would like to let the user know how many days are left each time they re-visit the page.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't retrieve it via server-side first, then you have to resort to using client-side tricks because you can't access this directly on the client-side. The trick is by using localStorage to store the cookie meta information, you an achieve this. For example, when setting the cookie, do the following:

```
document.cookie = 'mycookie=blah;expires=[expiredate];';
localStorage['mycookie'] = JSON.stringify({ 
   expires : '[expiredate]',
   otherdata: whatever
});
```

You can then check its meta data as you like. If the cookie does not exist, meaning its not in document.cookie , you should erase the localStorage for that cookie in your script.

The best way to do this is via server-side and output this as some var to the page if you must but for sure, don't store more information about the cookie in other cookies as this will only bloat the request unnecessarily.

Comment: How would you even detect is server side first?