# Cant set javascript cookie expiration date

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
function setMoney(value) {
    var myDate = new Date(2050, 9, 12);
    myDate.toUTCString();
    alert(document.cookie); //i get the old cookie as normal
    document.cookie = "money=" + value + ";expires=" + myDate + ";";
    alert(document.cookie); //i get money=987996 and i dont get the expiration date
}
setMoney(987996);
```

whats wrong here? it's like the code just stops at the + value + bit. chaning the number in the method calling line still results in a number change in the alert so i know it is setting something.

Answer (score 3):

alert wont give you expiration date, it will show only value. 
check your cookie with Firebug, it should be with proper expiration date.

Comment: why wont it do give the date?

Comment: document.cookie will give you array of cookies separated by ";"


below post may help you (i didnt try)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274875/how-to-get-cookie-expiration-date-creation-date-from-javascript

Comment: so how do i retrieve the money value. it comes up with money=934543 or whatever i set it to it doesnt have the semicolon

Comment: never mind i just removed the 'end' bit so the substring goes right to the end.