# set a expiration of cookies when inactive c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

i have this cookies

```
 HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("AuthorID", data.AuthorID.ToString());
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
 HttpContext.Response.AppendCookie(cookie2);
```

is there a possible way to set a time of expiration when cookies is inactive of the user of the site is not doing anything? for example reloading the page etc.

what i did is set a time for 1 min and its not working does anybody know?.
i'm having trouble i have search in the internet but i didn't find any useful advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something similar in my project.

Process:

1. For each request send a cookie.
2. On client side write a JavaScript code for reading the cookie when the page is loaded.
3. In JavaScript [check the expiration date of the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3274924).
4. If the cookie as expired (or not present) do your actions for inactive users (e.g. reload the page, display a message, disconnect him...).

You may also slightly change the above scenario like:

1. Set expiration date/time as cookie value.
2. Idem
3. Make sure cookie value < current date/time
4. Idem

If you care about users rejecting cookies you can do it in JavaScript without cookies. For example:

1. Set JavaScript variable 'lastActionTime'.
2. Create methods checking that 'lastActionTime' > time + delay
3. Attach common JavaScript events (clicks, focus...) and once called set 'lastActionTime' to the current time.