# How can i make cookies with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Let say i've the following function

```
<script language="javascript">

function myfunction() {
   alert("This function was successfully triggered");
}

myfunction(); // trigger it
</script>
```

I'd like to makes it drop cookie with a name and expiration 24 hours and every-time the user trigger the function `myfunction();`, it will check for cookies exist and valid or not

What i means is something like this scheme

1) `var cookie_name = cowboy;` // define name

2) Check of cookie with name `cowboy` exist and valid of 24 hours since today date.

- if exist and valid then do nothing
- if not exist or not valid then do the alert and drop cookie with name `cookie_name` for 24 hours and do the alert `alert("This function was successfully triggered");`

so any help how to rewrite this function to do so.

Comment: have u searched it before asking ... I don't think So.

Comment: Take a look at this SO article.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274875/how-to-get-cookie-expiration-date-creation-date-from-javascript

Comment: Here's is the example of javaScript cookies       (http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username)

Comment: @xK0nB1n thank you for posting this example and i will read it and make search for similar questions.

Comment: @MajdMahmoud have u got your answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use cookies like [this](http://goo.gl/2i3xg)

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}
```

call the function Inside **HTML**:

```
 <body onload="checkCookie()">
```

Comment: Thank you so much and based on your example and some searching results, i've do it and working perfect however still not sure about expiry date cause i can see it only check for the cookie by `cname`.

Comment: does `1*24*60*60*1000` means 1 day ?

Comment: @MajdMahmoud You can also refer to http://goo.gl/3Kor3I this explains more of that