# how to get time remains for cookie expiration in seconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have set cookie having 2 mins expiration time.
I want to display count-down on HTML, how much seconds are remaining to expire that particular cookie in angular 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274875/how-to-get-cookie-expiration-date-creation-date-from-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `<h2>{{countDown | async}}</h2>`
})
export class App {
   countDown;
   count = 60;

   constructor() {

       this.countDown = timer(0,1000).pipe(
          take(this.count),
          map(()=> --this.count)
       );
   }
}
```

so while setting cookie time you can set same time in timer too. make sure you assign your cookie time and this timer time same for exact working.

working example is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TWMIEd1UykUdUC37qyFK?p=preview)

Comment: this only shows count down, I want to get reaming time for cookie expire, how I can get it

Comment: so i have given you the logical answer you need to get time as mentioned in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274875/how-to-get-cookie-expiration-date-creation-date-from-javascript and pass the time to my function