# jQuery cookie expiration value

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have read a lot of jQuery cookie questions on here and know there is a jQuery cookie plugin ([jQuery cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)).  Without doing much investigation, the question: is there a way to determine expiration date of cookie?

From the jquery.cookie doc:

```
/**
* Get the value of a cookie with the given name.
*
* @example $.cookie('the_cookie');
* @desc Get the value of a cookie.
*
* @param String name The name of the cookie.
* @return The value of the cookie.
* @type String
*
* @name $.cookie
* @cat Plugins/Cookie
* @author Klaus Hartl/klaus.hartl@stilbuero.de
*/
```

Doesn't seem that this plugin can do it?

The reason I want to do this is that my cookie expires after 5 minutes of inactivity and Id like to notify user that their session is about to expire from Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something has changed, you can't get this value *from* a cookie, you can set it but that's it, when it expires it just won't show up in the cookie collection anymore....but you can't see that it expires in 5 minutes for example.

Your best bet for something along the lines of session expiration is to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) with the correct delay, for example if it's 5 minutes, you may want to alert at 4 min 30 seconds, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Your session will expire in 30 seconds!");
}, 270000);  //4.5 * 60 * 1000
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, thanks. Since I am updating the cookie via PHP on each subsequent page request, you are recommending that I just on each page request set a timeout of cookie.expiration - (some time) to fire off a message to user?  I guess I just do not understand why you can set a expiration but cannot get it back.

Comment: @Chris - I'm not sure the reasoning on that one, just know that the document/cookie API doesn't have methods to get it, if you look at `document.cookie` you'll see it isn't in there :)  And yes on including the timeout on every page, or just have that timeout directly in an included JavaScript file...I would do a notification bar or something besides an alert personally, but the idea's the same :)

Answer (score 7):

As it's not accessible from the JavaScript API, the only way is to store it in the content in parallel with the metadata.

```
  var textContent = "xxxx"
  var expireDays = 10;
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var expireDate = now + (1000*60*60*24*expireDays);
  $.cookie("myCookie", '{"data": "'+ textContent +'", "expires": '+ expireDate +'}', { expires: expireDays  });
```

Then read it back (obviously, add safeguards in case the cookie expired already) :

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var cookie = $.parseJSON($.cookie("myCookie"));
var timeleft = cookie.expires - now;
var cookieData = cookie.data;
```

Note this will not be entirely reliable if the client clock changes in the meantime, say, due to DST.

Comment: var cookie = $.parseJSON($.cookie("myCookie")); does not work.

@link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date

Comment: @user470370: Providing you do include Jquery and [the Cookie plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) and use correct json (I made a mistake, forgot quotes around keys of the json string) it works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/3ddLG/2/

Comment: please consider that you will have problems getting a value stored this way on server side. For example, in PHP, $_COOKIE['myCookie'] will only get the first characters of its value.

Answer (score 6):

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

Will expire in 7 days

there is no Javascript API that allows you to check the expiry date for a cookie

Comment: I want the expiration value.  I am not asking how to set the expiration value itself.

Comment: there is no Javascript API that allows you to check the expiry date for a cookie