# How do you test the expiration date on a cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I access the expiration time on a cookie in a functional test?  For example:

```
assert cookies.signed[:cart_id].expires > Time.now
```

That will throw an error because `cookies[:cart_id]` just returns the integer.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date), and many other pages I found on the web while looking for a solution to this, it is not possible.  It's not an issue with Rails, it's an issue with how the web (DOM) works.

You don't need to test for cookie expiry, the web browser does that for you. You can just poll your cookie; if it's expired, it won't exist, and the value returned will be either nil or you'll get an exception, I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: We are just trying to follow good TDD.  You can see the expiration if you inspect the cookie in the test, but can't figure out how to access it.