# How to detect cookie expiration in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

It seem `$watch` not work with cookies expires. Here is the code I tried

```
 $scope.$watch(function(){
        return $cookies.get('cookies')
    },function(newVal,oldVal){
        if(!newVal){
            console.log('ok')

        }
    })
```

I can check it with `$interval`. But I dont want call digest cycle every 2s , or 5s.

Comment: `$scope.watch` will watch cookie much more frequently than `every 2s or 5s`

Comment: @harishr yes , but it seem it not work when I delete cookies , or cookies expired

Comment: Watch functions are only triggered if there is a digest cycle. If there is no digest cycle, the watch function will not execute and will not detect the expiration of the cookie. Use $interval which is guaranteed to initiate a digest cycle at the specified interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [it is not possible to read the cookie expiration time in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date) so my first idea of iterating over them and executing action on their expiration dates is not possible.

If you don't want to start a digest on every "cookie check", you can disable invoking it with the fourth parameter for the `$interval` set to `false`. See the [`$interval` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Example code:

```
.run(function($cookies, $interval) {
  var previouslyAvailableCookies = Object.keys($cookies.getAll());
  var watchCookieChanges = function() {
     var availableCookies = Object.keys($cookies.getAll());
     var expiredCookies = previouslyAvailableCookies.filter(function(cookieName) { return availableCookies.indexOf(cookieName) < 0; });
     var newCookies = availableCookies.filter(function(cookieName) { return previouslyAvailableCookies.indexOf(cookieName) < 0; });
     if (expiredCookies.length || newCookies.length) {
       document.writeln("<p>New cookies: " + newCookies 
                      + "<br>Expired cookies: " + expiredCookies + '</p>');
     }
    previouslyAvailableCookies = availableCookies;
  };
  $interval(watchCookieChanges, 3000, 0, false);
})
```

And a [codepen](https://codepen.io/fracz/pen/yXpGep?editors=1010).