# Setting up cookie in Javascript (Angular): Issues with semicolon

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web, cookies

I was trying to set up cookies with TypeScript in Angular, when I encountered a seemingly weird problem.

I just wanted to store some information in a cookie for later use (testing purposes only). All I did was execute this line:

```
document.cookie = "token=" + value + "; expires=" + date + ";";
```

If I execute `document.cookie` afterwards however the result is as follows:

```
"Cookie: token=_value_"
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
"Cookie: token=_value_; expires=_date_;"
```

It just erases everything after the semicolon in the string. If I change them to commas instead everything gets concatenated correctly.
So there has to be some problem with semicolons? But in every "tutorial" for cookies they use this grammar. 
I tried many things like encoding semicolon values and what not. I'm sure there is a simple answer to this?

Comment: I didn't arrive to reproduce the problem but I it should be `document.cookie`.

Comment: My fault, of course I meant `document` instead of `window`!

Comment: When you read a cookie by document.cookie it will not show the expiry and path. To see those details use browser devtools.

Comment: Okay I did not know that, but I simplified the above code since I thought that would be okay. I had more "custom key-value pairs" and all of the time it only shows the first one.

Comment: See When you do document.cookie = "key=value; expiary=; path=/" it adds entry to cookie. So every time you call document.cookie a new entry is added to cookie. Better create a setCookie Utility function like setCookie(key,value,expiary).

Comment: I can't say that I completely understood the syntax/notation behind cookies, but that works for my purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a cookie it is with this form :

```
document.cookie = "key=value; property_1; property_2; ... property_n";
```

Based on [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Write_a_new_cookie) you can only write one new cookie at a time. If you want to declare two cookie you should do two assignments :

```
document.cookie = "key=value; property_1; property_2; ... property_n";
document.cookie = "key2=value2; property_1; property_2; ... property_n";
```

Now, **why you don't see the properties when you display `document.cookie` ?**

It is a normal behavior. `document.cookie` is in fact an **accessor property**. It means that JavaScript will use a getter and a setter when you use `document.cookie`. What you write in your code won't be what you will read later because it will respectively call a setter to assign a cookie `document.cookie = ...` and a getter to display `document.cookie`. **Everything is managed by the JavaScript interpreter internally.**

In your case, you are declaring **one cookie** with a value and an expiration date. The semi-colon `;` is used to specify other properties of the cookie you are creating.

```
document.cookie = "token=" + value + "; expires=" + date + ";";
```

Your example declare a new cookie with the name `token`, the value `value` and the property `expires`with a date contained by the `date` variable. It will call an internal JavaScript setter to set this cookie.

Now if you display all your cookies with `document.cookie`, you will only get the name and value of each cookie, not the other properties as `expires`, `path`, `secure` or `domain`. It is manage by a getter call internally which choose to display only the key=value pair of each cookie.

As mentionned in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date) you can't access other properties by `document.cookie`.

Comment: That makes sense I guess, even though I'm not quite sure on how to get the properties? And why does the cookie name needs a value? Anyways, you already helped me. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer. About the value, why declare a cookie if you don't need a value ? The name is here to access the value. The value is what you need to process something. It is the same principle of a variable or in some way a tag in HTML, it's here to allow the program to access it and understand what it is.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Much appreciated. I definitely got some things about cookies wrong. Thank you for clearing that up! :)

Comment: I would like to, but I don't have enough reputation. I'm sorry. ^^' I only have 14, but I need 15.

Comment: there you go ^^

Comment: Thank you, don't hesitate to ask for more details if you need.