# How do I check the HttpOnly cookie expiration time?

Tags: node.js

```
const token = jwt.sign({
    id: userid
}, process.env.JWT_SALT, {
    expiresIn: '1m'
});
res.cookie(
    'token',
    token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 500000),
        httpOnly: true
    }
).json({
    code: 200,
    message: "토큰이 발급되었습니다",
    token
});
```

I have the same code. Is there a way to check the token expiration time in React?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912808/5007662 You can store another cookie with the timestamp of the expiration of the first cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. According to the reply you gave, isn't it a part that can be used in a document cookie rather than an http cookie?

Answer (score 3):

It is never possible to get the expiration date of a cookie, even if it's not HTTP-only. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1532193/9253414), which is about getting it with JavaScript, but there's also no way to do it in the server-side.

I would suggest you to store the expiration date in the server side associated with the token or to store it in a separate cookie.

Comment: Can't I get an expiration time even for cookies issued with jwt?