# It is possible to know a cookie expiration date?

Tags: javascript, cookies

It is possible to know when a cookie expires? I have a function that gets a cookie:

```
function getCookie(cName) {
    const name = cName + "=";
    const cDecoded = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    const cArr = cDecoded .split('; ');
    let res;
    cArr.forEach(val => {
        if (val.indexOf(name) === 0) res = val.substring(name.length);
    })
    return res;
}
```

But I need to know the expiration date also, not only the value.

Does someone know? I couldn't find a solution.
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Reading cookie expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date)

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date/66621502#66621502

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:
You cant get a cookie expiration date, that's why you need to store the expiration date on another cookie.